# d3.js v3 and broken zoomable treemap example

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I've been trying to adapt the following example in a visualisation I've been creating.

http://bl.ocks.org/PMeinshausen/5806106

I was struggling for a long time because in my version, the 'on click' to zoom was not functioning.  I eventually figured out it's because the example at the link above uses d3 v2.  If you use v3, it no longer works.  So when I substitute in v2 my code works fine.

However, I can't work out example why it doesn't work with version 3.  I've looked at the [release notes](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Upgrading-to-3.0) for version 3, but they don't help me - probably because I don't understand them well enough.

However, as far as I can tell, the problem is not the 'on click' event binding e.g. in this code:

```
    /* transition on child click */
        g.filter(function(d) { return d.children; })
            .classed("children", true)
            .on("click", transition);
```

It seems like the for some reason the data at d.children doesn't exist when you use d3 v3.

Could anyone shed any light on what's going wrong or point me in the right direction for the part of the code I need to change?  Thanks very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the offending line in the zoomable treemap example is this one:

```
    .children(function(d, depth) { return depth ? null : d.children; })
```

Try replacing it with

```
    .children(function(d) { return d.children; })
```

I made this change and found that the treemap behaved as I would expect it to.

According to the [d3 documentation](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Hierarchy-Layout#_hierarchy), the hierarchy layout, as used by the treemap layout, adds a `children` property to each node, containing an array of all of the children of that node.  It happens that the JSON data used in this example already has such `children` properties for the arrays of child nodes.

Without making my suggested change, the offending line above tells d3 that nodes only have children if the depth is 0. If the depth is 1 or greater, there are no children.  The only node at level 0 is the `{children: d.children}` anonymous object passed to `treemap.nodes()`.  As each node of depth 1 or greater apparently has no children, d3 deletes the `children` properties from these nodes.  This causes the data at `d.children` to be missing.

With my suggested change in place, d3 computes the array of children of each node, and in each case this matches the original array in the data. So this child-array recomputation causes no apparent change.

As far as I can tell, d3 version 2 didn't compute and store arrays of nodes' children in the same way, so it wouldn't clobber any pre-existing arrays it found.

So, in summary, if you are using a d3 treemap (or any of the other hierarchical layouts), and your data is structured using properties with the name `children` which contain arrays of child nodes, then be careful how you tell the treemap to find child nodes within your data.

Comment: Thank you so much!  Frustrating because I was almost there (I'd experimented with swapping some `children` for `_children`.  Based on your post, I've now got a working solution.  In case the deletion of `return depth ? null` is important I managed to refactor it to rename the children elements rather than delete that code.  For future stackoverflow users, there's a working gist here:  https://gist.github.com/RobinL/827c3e53f6615dcc8d38